# Strategy for caching of remote service; what should I be considering?

Tags: database, api, caching, optimization

My web app contains data gathered from an external API of which I do not have control. I'm limited to about 20,000 API requests per hour. I have about 250,000 items in my database. Each of these items is essentially a cached version. Consider that it takes 1 request to update the cache of 1 item. Obviously, it is not possible to have a perfectly up-to-date cache under these circumstances. So, what things should I be considering when developing a strategy for caching the data. These are the things that come to mind, but I'm hoping someone has some good ideas I haven't thought of.

- time since item was created (less time means more important)
- number of 'likes' a particular item has (could mean higher probability of being viewed)
- time since last updated

A few more details: the items are photos. Every photo belongs to an event. Events that are currently occurring are more like to be viewed by client (therefore they should take priority). Though I only have 250K items in database now, that number increases rather rapidly (it will not be long until 1 million mark is reached, maybe 5 months).

Comment: Why can't you, for instance, just retrieve the 20K items which have changed or are new within the last hour at once and update only those in your DB? You don't need to check for 1Mio items for an update, when the you are querying at least once per hour?

Comment: Unless I use an API request, I have no way of knowing which items have been changed.

Comment: Yes, of course, but the request could filter for the newest changed requests in stead of just issuing one blind shot for one particular item? Which API are you accessing, Facebook?

Comment: Instagram. I'm confused, how is that different than the third point I listed: "time since last updated"

Comment: updated where - on Instagram or in your DB? I mean: changed on instagram since the last run of your query batch.

Comment: By "time since last updated" I mean: time since that item was last checked/updated via an API request.

Comment: How do items enter your DB, do you query for new or do people add themselves?

Comment: imagine, your cached data is 3 weeks old how would you get that it has just now change on instagram? You need to check for new data on the source, not on the drain.

Comment: there's not enough information here.  it's not even clear what the limitation is.  are the photos changing over time?  are new photos being added to the remote service at greater than 20,000/hr?  are you getting more than 20,000 requests/hr?  even the statement "obviously it ..." is wrong - if the data are not changing it's not obvious at all.  please give the numbers and a clearer explanation of what you are trying to do and where the bottleneck is.

Comment: @rovermicrover items enter db from cronjob that checks instagram for new/updated photos

Comment: @AxelAmthor yeah, you're describing the problem, but what's your point?

Comment: @andrewcooke yes, photos are being changed on the remote end at random times. that's why i need to get and cache the changes. usually less than 100 new photos are added per hour. 20k request per hour is the limitation (at least for discussion purposes).

Comment: so you have an api that tells you about new and changed photos, and less than 20.000 an hour are new or changed?  then what is the problem?  just update everything.

Comment: Any of the many photos in my database may be updated at any time. I have no way of knowing when a photo is updated. The only way to find out if a photo has been updated is to use a API request. I can't run a check on 250K photos every second, so I have to figure out a compromise. Is the problem clear now?

Comment: Does your system have to store the images in perpetuity, or is there some kind of elimination of older/something images?

Comment: @andyg0808 it needs to store a record of every photo, but of course photos that are very old are less likely to have changes to metadata and are less likely to be important (that is, viewed by a user)

Comment: i love this question. once the bounty is up, please remind me, im going to start another bounty and add 500 points. you should be able to get better answers. im willing to bet you will get much better responses if you try to reword your question and make it easier to understand. the amount of questions asked about your question indicates that it's not clear.

Comment: @АртёмЦарионов I think it is hard to answer the question because we don't know now a lot about current site. Hence I answered very generically to lead OP to better understanding of photo views on his site.

Comment: im very confused as to why i am unable to offer bounty here

Comment: perhaps they disabled my ability to give bounties since i awareded like 10,000 point already hahahahah

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Would http://instagram.com/developer/realtime/ be any use? It appears that Instagram is willing to POST to your server when there's new (and maybe updated?) images for you to check out. Would that do the trick?

Otherwise, I think your problem sounds much like the problem any search engine has—have you seen [Wikipedia on crawler selection criteria](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_crawler#Selection_policy)? You're dealing with many of the problems faced by web crawlers: what to crawl, how often to crawl it, and how to avoid making too many requests to an individual site. You might also look at [open-source crawlers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_crawler#Open-source_crawlers) (on the same page) for code and algorithms you might be able to study.

Anyway, to throw out some thoughts on standards for crawling:

- Update the things that have changed often when updated. So, if an item hasn't changed in the last five updates, then maybe you could assume it won't change as often and update it less.
- Create a score for each image, and update the ones with the highest scores. Or the lowest scores (depending on what kind of score you're using). This is a similar thought to what is used by LilyPond to [typeset music](http://www.lilypond.org/doc/v2.16/Documentation/essay/automated-engraving). Some ways to create input for such a score:

  - A statistical model of the chance of an image being updated and needing to be recached.
  - An importance score for each image, using things like the recency of the image, or the currency of its event.
- Update things that are being viewed frequently.
- Update things that have many views.
- Does time affect the probability that an image will be updated? You mentioned that newer images are more important, but what about the probability of changes on older ones? Slow down the frequency of checks of older images.
- Allocate part of your requests to slowly updating everything, and split up other parts to process results from several different algorithms simultaneously. So, for example, have the following (numbers are for show/example only--I just pulled them out of a hat):

  - 5,000 requests per hour churning through the complete contents of the database (provided they've not been updated since the last time that crawler came through)
  - 2,500 requests processing new images (which you mentioned are more important)
  - 2,500 requests processing images of current events
  - 2,500 requests processing images that are in the top 15,000 most viewed (as long as there has been a change in the last 5 checks of that image, otherwise, check it on a decreasing schedule)
  - 2,500 requests processing images that have been viewed at least
  - *Total:* 15,000 requests per hour.

Comment: http://instagram.com/developer/realtime/ is being used in addition to other methods. However, it only notifies me of new photos, not changes to existing photos and their metadata.

Comment: this is the type of answer I'm looking for, thanks. I'm waiting to see what other people say though.

Comment: This answer is great; gives a lot of strategies that you can employ all at once. Ultimately, you'll need to balance them using a heuristic that gives you the best behavior in practice.

Answer (score 1):

How many (unique) photos / events are viewed on your site per hour? Those photos that are not viewed probably don't need to be updated often. Do you see any patterns in views for old events / phones? Old events might not be as popular so perhaps they don't have to be checked that often.

andyg0808 has good detailed information however it is important to know the patterns of your data usage before applying in practice.

At some point you will find that 20,000 API requests per hour will not be enough to update frequently viewed photos, which might lead you to different questions as well.